# Data Weave not able to escape the string inside double quotes- Mule ESB

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, dataweave

I'm trying to convert csv to csv. My deliliter is `,`, there are certain texts in input which also comes as with comma example: `"Fun,Chair,tables"` but it will be wrapped with quotes. Data Weave thinks this is as delimiter and separates in to different column in response.

Please find the  Input CSV file

```
 sequence,items
 1,Fun
 2,"Fun,chairs,tables"
 3,Games
```

But getting response as

```
Number,itemDetails
1,Fun
2,Fun\,Chair\,tables
3,Games
```

In the above response, second two is splitted which i'm not expecting
my dataweaver

```
  %dw 1.0
  %output application/csv header=true 
   ---
  payload map { 
   Number:$.sequence,
   itemDetails:$.items
```

Expected response is

```
 Number,itemDetails
 1,Fun
 2,"Fun,chairs,tables"
 3,Games
```

Problem here is `"Fun,chairs,tables"`, double quotes should go as test field, instead `data weaver` consider this as a delimiter.
In the Data weave header,tried with `quote= " "` and `escape=" "`. But not working.
I have tried same thing on Datamapper working perfectly fine. Believe somethings needs to be done on header, not sure what but??. 
Checked the properties in read configuration properties in Data Weave CSV settings also. No help.

Edit:
With the DataWeaver escape sequence, 
`%output application/csv header=true escape="\""`
Below is the response

```
Number,itemDetails
1,Fun
2,Fun",Chair",tables
3,Games
```

Your thoughts and suggestions will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have solution for this ? we do have same issue

Comment: @tortoise:Nope.I haven't find the solution.Hence haven't updated from Datamapper to DW. Post here if you find any.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try escape="\"" ? I think this will escape the double quotes

Comment: I have tried with the escape. Not seems to be working!

Comment: Edited question with the escape sequence response.Please provide your thoughts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
%output application/csv quoteValues=true ,escape =" "
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the value in quotes by yourself

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/csv header=true
---
payload map ((item , index) -> {
    Number: item.sequence,
    itemDetails: item.items
} when index != 1
otherwise {
    Number: item.sequence,
    itemDetails: "\"" ++ item.items ++ "\""
})
```

**Output**

```
Number,itemDetails
1,Fun
2,"Fun\,chairs\,tables"
3,Games
```

Answer (score 0):

we have to change the reader property like below. I've also faced the same problem while reading the csv input.

```
<dw:reader-property name="escape" value="&quot;"/>
```

above worked in my case and solved the problem